# OLEDB Import of Chinese Unicode characters

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm attempting to batch import excel data in VBA using

```
cnn1.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & Excelfile & ";" & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
rst1.Open "SELECT * FROM [A1:E502];", cnn1, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

The data includes a mix of English and Chinese characters and unfortunately the imported data sets all Chinese characters to '?'

For example, 'Portfolio 保證組合' imports as 'Portfolio ????'

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Comment: This isn't actually an issue for me now in this case. Although the VBA variables are displaying ?? when it's written back to Excel it comes out correctly. I'm just glad I don't have to manipulate the strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of words and put the chars of the string into the array.
Now you can see the character codes that get imported.